# How do I initialize the contents of my 2d array of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, 2d

So I created a function with the code:

```
#define ATABLE 20

void func1(){
char array[ATABLE][ATABLE];
int row, col;

for(row=0; row<ATABLE; row++)
    for(col=0; col<ATABLE; col++)
{
    array[row][col]={' '};
}
}
```

But there is an error message when I compile it and it says "expected expression before '{' token" I think there is something wrong with my initialization but I can't seem to figure out how to correctly implement it. If I wanted to initialize all the elements of my 2d array with, let's say, a space, how do I write it? All answers would be very much appreciated. TIA

Comment: This should be tagged with the proper language tag so the right people will see it.

Comment: Please show how you declared `array` as well.

Comment: Why are there braces? Just write `array[row][col]= ' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you putting braces around the single character? If `array` is an array of array of `char`, just put

```
array[row][col] = ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you declared `array`, but you could try this:

```
array[row][col] = " ";
```

Comment: Already tried that but it shows a warning: assignment makes integer without a cast

Answer (score 0):

If this is in java:

```
//Assumes ATABLE has been pre-initialized.
char[][]  array = new char[ATABLE][ATABLE];
for (int row = 0; row < ATABLE; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < ATABLE; col++)
    {
        array[row][col] = ' ';
    }
}
```